# Rmd: Make the figure larger when clicked on it

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a Rmarkdown file where I include figures with

> knitr::include_graphics

The figures show up in the knitted document nicely. However, when I'm reading the knitted document, if I want to focus on one figure, I use the zoom option of the browser, which is not ideal.

Is it possible to add open the figure in a larger window when clicked on it?

PS: I use gitbook and/or bookdown::html for the output format of my Rmd files.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out the themes from [rmdformats package](https://github.com/juba/rmdformats) which implement this feature. They call it lightbox. To enable,you just need to set lightbox to true in the RMD yaml.

Example:

```
---
title: "My document"
output:
  rmdformats::downcute:
    lightbox: true
---
```

Comment: but then I can't use all the functionalities that bookdown provides

Comment: ahh, forgot to see that part. There is a yaml option `use_bookdown` which you can set to TRUE to use `bookdown` for rendering. That will probably churn out a bookdown? If that doesn't work either, you will probably have to tamper with the javascript in your bookdown template and add the functionality manually.

Comment: Unfortunately that broke a couple of things in my document, even with `use_bookdown: true`. Thanks for mentioning though.